# Google asks to update your Android targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, google-play, targetsdkversion

Google recently announced, that ***"updates to apps and games on Google Play will be required to target Android 9 (API level 28) or higher"***. As far as I understand, this does not have any negative consequences (like, the apps are removed from store) to existing apps with a targetSdkVersion lower than 28. Is this true? So, what google wants to say is just that I'm no longer able to update existing apps with targetSdkVersion < 28?

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to update the existing apps after the given timeline. This is because some developers abuse the API by targeting the old API level like targeting API 21 so that they don't have to ask for runtime permission.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746

Comment: Interesting idea. I was just curious if they gonna delete my apps when I don't re-compile and upload my apps. Thanks @Somesh Kumar.

Comment: @thomasgalliker It is highly unlikely. There are thousands of unupdated apps which are still in use by thousands of users.

Comment: It happened to me recently. One of my customer's apps was "too old" so they removed it from Play Store. That's why I'm super paranoid now.

Comment: Hope the one who downvoted has a reason for it. Thanks for those who seriously contribute.

Comment: I contacted Google and they said they "can't guarantee what happen" if they app is unupdated past this day.. sooooo!

Answer (score 2):

Last year Google notified developers to upgrade your Apps which should be at least API-LEVEL 26.
Now same thing we have to do upgrade API-Level, existing applications will not stop or removed but new builds we can not publish on play store which are below> API Level  28.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, starting from November 1 Google won't allow you to submit to console if the target is less than 28